# What differences are between IIS 7.0 and IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I thought that **IIS 7.0** and **IIS 7.5** have (from the application developer point of view) nearly same features. Then, I found that [certain features are not working on **IIS 7.0**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366925/iis-returns-404-for-asp-net-mvc3-file-cshtml/7367360). Are there more features available in **IIS 7.5** that are missing in **IIS 7.0** (that application developer should know)?

(Maybe not core **IIS** features, but some other **ASP.NET (MVC)** features that are working on **IIS 7.0**.)

Comment: Do you have any specific problems about your ASP.NET MVC project running under IIS?

Comment: Yes, I have a problem with plain .cshtml files on IIS 7.0 (check the link in the question). And I also want to know what other features (I may use) are not working on IIS 7.0.

Comment: Are you running your application under a Classic Mode App Pool?

Comment: No, 4.0 integrated.

Comment: Turn on Failed Request Tracing on the IIS and see what you get there.

Comment: I was trying to turn of Failed Request Tracing and I have found that I did not have tracing installed. But in the meantime I have found it:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366925/iis-returns-404-for-asp-net-mvc3-file-cshtml/7457933#7457933

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general pointers:

- http://blogs.iis.net/mailant/archive/2009/10/22/general-availability-of-windows-7-amp-windows-server-2008-r2-with-iis-7-5.aspx
- http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-server-2008-r2-new-features-the-complete-list-part-3-iis-75-and-performance/
- http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression
- Bug fixes
- FTP Publishing Service 7.5
- WebDAV 7.5
- Client Certificate Mapping
- IP Security
- Request Filtering
- URL Authorization

Answer (score 3):

Following article should help you :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939979(WS.10).aspx

In order to sum it up :

> Many features have been added or enhanced in Internet Information
>   Services (IIS) 7.5. The following changes are available:
>
> Integrated extensions
>
> - WebDAV and FTP
> - Request Filtering
> - Administration Pack modules
>
> Management enhancements
>
> - IIS Module for Windows PowerShell
> - Configuration logging and tracing
>
> Application hosting enhancements
>
> - Service hardening
> - Managed service accounts
> - Hostable Web Core
> - Failed Request Tracing for FastCGI

Comment: +1 Thx, for the link and the summary.